# Converting ISO 8601 timestamp String to java.time.OffsetDateTime

Tags: java, java-8, iso8601

Let's say I have a date in ISO 8601 format: `"2017-01-10T14:55:32+01:00"`.

How do I convert it to **OffsetDateTime**?

I haven't found any answer here. I tried following:

```
public OffsetDateTime stringToOffsetDateTime() {
        return OffsetDateTime.from(Instant.parse("2019-12-12T10:39:40-02:00"));
    }
```

But it throws `DateTimeParseException`.

Comment: `OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-01-10T14:55:32+01:00", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)`

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes - please provide comments how I can improve the question

Comment: Lemme guess, the downvotes may be because you had not shown an effort; usually we expect the asker’s best attempt in the question, it’s really a better starting point for helping. Now you’ve put it in the answer instead. :-)

Comment: I edited for clarification, I hope now it's OK. No similar question on Stack, so it should save some people's time. From my perspective asking such question is an input to the community and shouldn't be downvoted. Just think how many times have you searched "How to convert X to Y" type of answer. I did it many times :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shortest answer is:

```
OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-01-10T14:55+01:00")
```

It recognizes ISO 8601 format by default (using DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME).

If needed, you can use other formaters in this way:

```
OffsetDateTime.parse(iso8601String, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE);
```

All the formaters can be browsed here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

The attempt from OP has failed because formatter from Instant was used. This naturally failed because Instant is always in UTC so even if possible you'd loose time zone info.